# Better folder view in Outlook 2016 on Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook, one can organize their emails in folders and subfolders in their inbox's left pane. However, the left pane view is not very convenient (not enough folders are shown on screen, hard to gauge the levels of hierarchy, cannot navigate with the keyboard, etc.).

Is there a way to have a Windows explorer-like view to sort emails more quickly and efficiently, or really any more efficient view of the folders?